# How to merge 2 JSON array files?

Tags: python, json, io

I have multiple files with JSON arrays from web scraping. They all look somewhat like this:

```
db_1.txt
[
{"title": "Title1", "price" : 21.37},
{"title": "Title2", "price" : 32.10},
{"title": "Title3", "price" : 221.67}
]

db_2.txt
[
{"title": "Title4", "price" : 121.37},
{"title": "Title5", "price" : 232.10}
]
```

How can I merge those files together while keeping same JSON array format? I obviously tried appending line by line with removing or adding ',' where needed but this is not probably as elegant and memory efficient way possible.

Comment: You have a way which works - why do you believe it is not elegant or memory-efficient? If you have working code which you think could be improved generally (especially in subjective matters like elegance), http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask. If you have a specific performance problem with your code (based on benchmarking), you can ask here but you should post your code and details of how you have benchmarked it.

Comment: Generally, you would deseralize both, concatenate the resulting lists, then serialize that. Are you actually operating with low memory?

Comment: *If* you are actually encountering memory issues, it is easier to switch to an alternative format, json-lines, to process it one record at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function of the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module that Python provides out of the box in order to read and process the json structures inside these `.txt` files and then append them to a final list in order to use it any way you want:

```
import json

result = []
textFiles = ['db_1.txt', 'db_2.txt']
for textFile in textFiles:
    with open(textFile, 'r') as file_1:
        data = json.loads(file_1.read())
        result.extend(data)

print(result)
```

This will print:

```
[{'title': 'Title1', 'price': 21.37}, {'title': 'Title2', 'price': 32.1}, {'title': 'Title3', 'price': 221.67}, {'title': 'Title4', 'price': 121.37}, {'title': 'Title5', 'price': 232.1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

db_1.txt

```
{
    merged_files:[
          "tile1":"title2","price"
          "tilte3":"title4","price"
      ]
}


]
```